# Applied css is working for both chrome and mozilla which should be applied only to mozilla

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply space at the bottom of the pop up by using the below css and html code because I have issue only with mozilla browser that I am not getting space at the end of the pop up.Below is my code that I have used but I need to decrease the more space which I have in chrome browser and need to add little space for mozilla browser. How can I do this?

```
<style type="text/css">
       @@-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .bottom {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            bottom: 0;
            flex: 1; /*Added*/
            background: white;
        }
    }
</style>
<div class=bottom>
   <table>
      <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   </table>
</div>

<div id="maindiv" style="max-height: 450px; overflow-y: auto; width: 98%; padding:15px 10px 55px;">
//pop up logic in main div getting space at the end of ui in chrome but not in fire fox
</div>
```

I need to decrease the more space which I have in chrome browser and need to add little space for Mozilla browser. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You must use one `@` sign.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .bottom {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        flex: 1; /*Added*/
        background: white;
    }
}
```

This is for Chrome:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){ 
    .bottom {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        flex: 1; /*Added*/
        background: white;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I need to decrease the more space which i have in chrome browser and need to add little space for mozilla browser how can i do this

Comment: I have already tried that but if i use single @ its is not getting accepted as css even though my css is in <style type="text/css"></style>

Comment: yeah. you can use specific **css** for **mozilla** and also create another hack for chrome. like this **@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
  .block{
      background-color: #FF0000;
  }  
}**

Comment: can you show me how to use this  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){ .block{ background-color: #FF0000; } }  by editing your answer in the post

Comment: i tried but it is not at all getting recognized as css if i use single @

Comment: I think the problem comes with your browsers versions. Check your versions and please search for hint in google. you can search like *chrome css hack*. you will be get more information about this

Answer (score 0):

use signle **@** instead of double **@@**

```
<style type="text/css">
       @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        .bottom {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            bottom: 0;
            flex: 1; /*Added*/
            background: white;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I need to decrease the more space which i have in chrome browser and need to add little space for mozilla browser how can i do this

Comment: I have already tried that but if i use single @ its is not getting accepted as css even though my css is in <style type="text/css"></style>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@supports` with a `calc(0s)` expression in conjunction with
`@-moz-document` to test for Stylo — Gecko does not support time values
in `calc()` expressions but Stylo does:

```
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    @supports (animation: calc(0s)) {
        .bottom {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            bottom: 0;
            flex: 1; /*Added*/
            background: white;
        }
    }
}
</style>
```